# Stuck in TTY1 screen

Tags: boot, login, gui, tty, 22.10

I installed Ubuntu 22.10 yesterday. Today when I turned it on it shows Ubuntu version my computer name TTY1 asks for my computer login but it's not working it says
Dev loop12: unable to read RDB block 8

Comment: Is it possible that you have a disk IO problem? You can boot from a live image and test disk and memory. If everything is OK, you can reinstall Ubuntu 22.10 and after that take a note of what you do on the system that you are not sure of what its consequences are.

Comment: Can you try to login via tty? If you remember root password, can you try to login via root in tty? If you don't remember root password. Please go ahead and try to recover it(https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password). Further, if you are successfully login to root. 
Please try doing full upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for the support I logged in and tried reinstalling the Ubuntu gui that fixed the problem